# How to pass value form one panel to another panel on same dashboard in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have a table panel with user details. If I click a row in a table I need to pass userId and display user details to another panel on the same dashboard. For that, *How to pass values(userId) from one panel to another panel on the same dashboard?* Is that achievable on Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box? Not possible. Maybe plugins exist that I'm not aware of? Check out the [Grafana Toolkit](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/master/packages/grafana-toolkit).

The closest you can get to such an interactive experience is using dashboard variables and multiple dashboards for different dimensions you can switch between while retaining selected variables and time ranges.